# d'Alembert Solution of fixed end

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

in  d'Alembert Solution for fixed end semi infinite string problem with wave equation $u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}$,we get 
$0= \frac{f(ct)+f(-ct)}{2} + \frac{\int_{-ct}^{ct}g(s)ds}{2c}$ where $f$ and $g$ are initial displacement and initial velocity function

but then my textbook says like 'this is possible when $f$ and $g$ are odd function'.but how can i justify that,i can select two function such that this expression become $0$,can anybody please explain why they are taking like that?,what is the logic behinde this?
for details http://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/pde1/dAlembert/dAlembert.htm

Comment: Remember that the solution is a sum of two travelling waves one moving to the right and one to the left; the shape of these individual arbitrary functions with respect to x stays constant, however the functions are translated left and right with time at the speed c.

Comment: that is okk,but how that account for getting $f$ and $g$ becomes odd for fixed end problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, if we take $x=0$ in d'Alembert's solution we get
\begin{align}
u(0,t)&=\frac{1}{2}[f(ct)+f(-ct)]+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{-ct}^{ct}g(s)\,ds \\
&=\frac{1}{2}[f(ct)+f(-ct)]+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{0}^{ct}[g(s)+g(-s)]\,ds. \tag{1} 
\end{align}
If $f$ and $g$ are odd functions, then $f(-ct)=-f(ct)$ and $g(-s)=-g(s)$, hence the RHS of $(1)$ vanishes for all $t$, i.e., the boundary condition $u(0,t)=0$ is automatically satisfied.